# Waiting before returning the source in Selenium (not timeout())

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to webcrawl [this website](https://images.nga.gov/en/search/do_quick_search.html?q=%221949.7.1%22). As you can see, upon opening, it'll first show a first, wrong page for a few seconds, before loading the actual, right page I'm interested in.

For clarity. [First/wrong page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7sZ.png) and the [second, right page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib5aJ.png)

As expected, using `BeautifulSoup` or `Requests` I only manage to get the html for the 'first page', and not the 'right' page.

I've tried using `Selenium` and `set_page_load_timeout()`, which only returns the 'first/wrong' page instead of the actual page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(7)
url = 'https://images.nga.gov/en/search/do_quick_search.html?q=%221949.7.1%22'
driver.get(url)
source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(source)
```

I've tried looking for related questions, but they're all about setting a timeout, which does not seem to be the problem here, since a page is loading, it's just not the page I want.

Is there a way to get the `source` after 7 seconds? (i.e. waiting 7 seconds before getting the source, instead of having a timeout after 7 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`title_is()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_is) [expected condition](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) to wait for a particular moment when required page is opened (page title changed from `"Just a moment..."` to `"National Gallery of Art | NGA Images"`):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://images.nga.gov/en/search/do_quick_search.html?q=%221949.7.1%22'
title = "National Gallery of Art | NGA Images"
driver.get(url)
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_is(title))
source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(source)
```

Comment: Here the 10 in wait() is the timeout? I.e. if the EC is true after x seconds, it'll continue as long as x < 10?

Comment: Yes, 10 seconds is timeout. If title remains the same after 10 seconds, you'll get `TimeOutException`